# rustdoc no_main "crate-level attribute should be in the root module"

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

When using the [`no_main`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/crates-and-source-files.html#the-no_main-attribute) outer attribute in Rust, [`cargo doc`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/commands/cargo-doc.html) complains about `unused attribute` and that `crate-level attribute should be in the root module`.

I am using Cargo 1.42.0-nightly.

Relevant code:

```rust
// main.rs

#![no_main]
```

This only happens when invoking `cargo doc`; `cargo build` works as expected.

I have seen https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/62184, which however does not contain any answer.
I have also seen https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/43144, from where I followed to https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/64471, but even though that merge request is already merged, the problem remains.

How to solve this warning?

Answer (score 3):

This warning is caused by [known bug in cargo/rustdoc](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/62184) which has however not yet been fixed.

As of now, this can be easily worked around by using the [`cfg_attr` attribute](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/conditional-compilation.html#the-cfg_attr-attribute) in combination with the rustdoc's [`cfg(doc)`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rustdoc/advanced-features.html#cfgdoc-documenting-platform-feature-specific-information) in the following way:

```rust
// main.rs

#![cfg_attr(not(doc), no_main)]
```

This code applies the `no_main` attribute in all cases, except when the documentation is building.